# Changing basedir in ant project

Tags: xml, ant

I'm having a list of projects each with ant build script, I need to write anther ant script that call all the other scripts (i.e: build all the projects from one build script), I thought of something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project basedir="../path/of/the/destination/project" default="build" name="Main Builder">
    <target name="build">
        <ant antfile="first.xml"/>
        <ant antfile="second.xml"/>
        <!--And so on-->  
    </target>
</project>
```

The problem is that the `basedir` attribute has to be the one of the project to be built, and so needs to be changed each time before building the next project.
How can I do so?

Comment: Please show your folder structure.

Comment: all the projects are in the same directory

Comment: Why do you have multiple ant files in the same directory?  wouldn't you abe able to have one build.xml and just add targets?  Why are you setting basedir to the destination rather than the projects actual base directory (which is .)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found that `ant` task takes an attribute `dir` that defines where to execute the ant script, so it'll be like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project basedir="../path/of/the/parent/directory" default="build" name="Main Builder">
    <target name="build">
        <ant antfile="buildScript1.xml" dir="project1"/>
        <ant antfile="buildScript2.xml" dir="project1"/>
        <ant antfile="buildScript3.xml" dir="project1"/>
        <!--And so on-->  
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You `basedir` should point to the directory which contain all projects and then give the relative path in `antfile`. Do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project basedir="../path/of/the/destination" default="build" name="Main Builder">
    <target name="build">
        <ant antfile="project1/buildScript.xml"/>
        <ant antfile="project2/buildScript.xml"/>
        <ant antfile="project3/buildScript.xml"/>
        <!--And so on-->  
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: tried that but it didn't work, that makes it build in parent directories.